# How to save file to HDFS with Pyspark deploy-mode cluster?

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs

I am using 3 computers to run a `pyspark` job. 1 computer is the master node and computer A, B is the slave node.

I have a list like this and I want to save this as a text file on the HDFS:

```
data = [['1', '2'], ['3']]
```

This is how I save the list as a text file on the HDFS:

```py
def save_file_hdfs(data, session, path):
    """
    Use this to save the file to HDFS.
    The saved file will be named "part-00000"
    """
    # First need to convert the list to parallel RDD
    rdd_list = session.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

    # Use the map function to write one element per line and write all elements to a single file (coalesce)
    rdd_list.coalesce(1).map(lambda row: str(row)).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Main code:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

output_path = "hdfs:///user/output"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("build_graph").getOrCreate()

save_file_hdfs(data, spark, output_path)
```

Run command:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
example.py
```

Then I got this error from the `stdout` file of computer A, the computer B is run normally:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connected.py", line 158, in <module>
    save_file_hdfs(data, spark, output_path)
  File "example.py", line 135, in save_file_hdfs
    rdd_list.coalesce(1).map(lambda row: str(row)).saveAsTextFile(path)
  File "/tmp/hadoop-tnhan/nm-local-dir/usercache/tnhan/appcache/application_1621226092496_0024/container_1621226092496_0024_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1656, in saveAsTextFile
  File "/tmp/hadoop-tnhan/nm-local-dir/usercache/tnhan/appcache/application_1621226092496_0024/container_1621226092496_0024_02_000001/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/tmp/hadoop-tnhan/nm-local-dir/usercache/tnhan/appcache/application_1621226092496_0024/container_1621226092496_0024_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
  File "/tmp/hadoop-tnhan/nm-local-dir/usercache/tnhan/appcache/application_1621226092496_0024/container_1621226092496_0024_02_000001/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o111.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://tnhanComputer:9000/user/output already exists
```

If I run it without setting the `master yarn deploy-mode cluster`, it runs normally.

Do you know why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, the path already exists `FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://tnhanComputer:9000/user/output already exists`

Comment: I believe it exists because computer B created it because there is no error from computer B. I thought two computers just help distribute the data and in the end, it will save to a single file?

Comment: No I think it exists because you created it with previous run (with deploy mode client). Try different path

Comment: I have already deleted all the folders on HDFS before I run it with `deploy-mode cluster`. If it true, why computer B can run it without any error?

Comment: I am confused about this: Do 2 computers save 2 different output files or combine them into a single file? I am quite new to `pyspark` so there are many things I haven't known yet.

Comment: Ah I think I see what is going on: so you passed a single path to your function, each executor will use that as the file path, that’s why when A works, B wouldn’t and vice versa. You might want to add some random numbers after your file path so rdd would be saved differently. Dataframe has this built-in but Since you’re saving in a custom way, you have to make this happens manually.

Comment: Yes, that right. How can I make it save a different path with my code? Is there any function that helps me get the `id` of the computer or something like that?

Comment: You can simply generate some random numbers or random `uuid`, append it into your file path in your function